# haproxy do multiple checks and using different ports

Tags: haproxy

At the moment i am using HAproxy to check an smtp server with the following:

```
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check expect rstring ^220
    tcp-check send QUIT\r\n
    tcp-check expect rstring ^221
```

But is it also possible to add in another check for the same service? This other check will be on port 80 and is a simple check to see if the IPHERE:80/mhtest   will return the string "GOOD"

If either checks come back with an error i want my service to change to the backup one i have

```
server node1 192.168.0.1:25 check-send-proxy check inter 15s send-proxy
server node2 192.168.0.2:25 check-send-proxy check inter 15s send-proxy backup
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Which OS?

Comment: centos 6.5  latest hproxy

Comment: You can write your own little health check application that connects to both services and whatever else, opening a health port on success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use the external health check i.e:

```
external-check path "/usr/bin:/bin"
 external-check command /bin/true
 server s1 10.0.0.3:4444 check
```